# Spring Cloud Contract Stubs Without Priorities

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-cloud-contract

Is there any way that Stubs created by Spring Cloud Contract match only if the request is exactly the same and not have to deal with priorities?

e.g. If there are 2 stubs with url /users?id=1&id=2 and /users, by default, even if I send a request to /users?id=1&id=2, the /users will be matched so I have to set the priority to /users e.g. to 2 and for /users?id=1&id=2 set it to 1 for it to work.